# Catch click-event of button in external app

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation

I would like to know whether a button in an external app is clicked.
Before I had to do the clicking myself, for which I used the following code:

```
//Get window
IntPtr wrapUp = Win32API.FindWindowByText(Win32API.GetDesktopWindow(), "WRAP-UP");
if ((int)wrapUp > 0)
{
    Win32API.SetFocus(wrapUp);
    IntPtr okButton = Win32API.FindWindowByText(wrapUp, "OK");
    Win32API.SetFocus(okButton);
    Win32API.PostMessage(okButton, Win32API.BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
}
```

But now I need to know when the user clicks that button.
Is there a way to do this?

I've been searching a bit and I've found several ways to perform the clicking from code, but not for listening to an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set an event hook function and listen to `EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED` which indicates that an object was invoked (such as a button clicked).

Comment: Doesn't look that simple. But after going through the docs, I think this is indeed the way to go. Thx.